# Delay thread start during map function call concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python-3.x, threadpoolexecutor, concurrent.futures

Is there a way to delay map function each Iterator by 3 sec when using concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor. I'm able to achieve thread processing but want to delay thread start by 3 sec

```
print(data)

Row(('Robert', 'Hoit', None, None, 'TX'), {'fname': 0, 'lname': 1, 'Age': 2, 'Gender': 3, 'State': 4})
Row(('James', 'Burns', 34, 'M', 'CA'), {'fname': 0, 'lname': 1, 'Age': 2, 'Gender': 3, 'State': 4})
Row(('Matt', 'Dan', 45, None, 'NY'), {'fname': 0, 'lname': 1, 'Age': 2, 'Gender': 3, 'State': 4})
```

data is a rowiterator that contain tuple and dict inside tuple. example above

```
func(values)
    for v in values;
        print(v) #logic present here

ex = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)
        r = ex.map(func, data, timeout=10)
```

Comment: why not `time.sleep(3)` before the map statement.

Comment: Updated the description to what i was looking for. Was looking for the delay on each iterator during the thread running

Answer (score 0):

This was asked a while ago now, but instead of using `ex.map`, you could use `ex.submit` in a loop with `sleep`.

```
r = []

for d in data:
   r.append(ex.submit(func, d))
   sleep(3)
```